# How to use a condition in multiple nested objects in GrapgQl

Tags: graphql, graphiql

I am a newbie in GraphQL and just started to use it in a react project. I have this query to fetch products data by a condition and pagination:

```
query ProductSearch($displayText_contains: String = " ", $skip: Int, $first: Int) {
  product(
    where: {displayText_contains: $displayText_contains}
    skip: $skip
    orderBy: {displayText: ASC}
    first: $first
  ) {
    displayText <------------- first
    id
    bag {
      contentItems {
        ... on ProductAdvantage {
          displayText    <------------- add where condition
          htmlBody {
            html
          }
          productId {
            contentItems {
              ... on Product {
                id
              }
            }
          }
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As it's shown I want to add a condition to `displayText` of `ProductAdvantage` object but I don't know how. While the condition on the first displayText works fine.

Comment: How are you applying the condition on the first one? How do you get data for contentItems?

Comment: This is the result from Orchard Core GraphiQl